# Connection drops when using Packet Capture in Android

Tags: android, networking

I am trying to analyze traffic for an app on Android and for some reason all connections, including the app to be analyzed stop working IF I leave packet capture running.

I've tried:

```
1. Turning off Wi-Fi and using LTE connection
2. Installed certificates, (CN=Packet Capture CA Certificate)
3. Status showing Installed to Trusted Credentials
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved? I am facing a similar issue

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357118/packet-capture-app-once-started-doesnt-have-internet-connectivity-for-other-app